# Block internet for a specific user, permanently

Tags: systemd, iptables, services, rc.local

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223434/how-to-disable-internet-for-a-user-on-a-system/223442#223442) works:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner {USERNAME} -j REJECT
```

to block internet for a specific user. But it's not permanent.

**What's the easiest way to make this persistent after a reboot, with newer systems (with `systemd`)?**

Creating a specific `.service` file is always tricky and takes some time to figure out: one-shot? stoppable? forking? etc. and [many other options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), so I was wondering what is the most natural way to persist a `iptables` rule with new systems.

Comment: you can persist your iptable rules with iptables-save like `iptables-save >/etc/sysconfig/iptables`. But if you have firewalld service, you shouldn't use both and need to disable that and enable `iptables-services` service.

Comment: just install `iptables-persistent`, and you're done, no?

Comment: Thanks @binarysta. Is there a way to block permanently, and sometimes unblock it (from command line with a password) and have it blocked again on reboot ?

Comment: you can persist the rule in a file, then anytime you remove it with `iptables command` the rule will be disabled but in the next boot the rules will be read from the file, so you have all your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Debian/Ubuntu based distros this link is useful [persist iptable rules](https://ahelpme.com/linux/ubuntu/save-iptables-rules-over-reboots-on-ubuntu-16-and-ubuntu-18-persistent-iptables-rules/), and also [this one](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-make-iptables-rules-persistent-after-reboot-on-linux):

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

For Redhat-based distros:
The package `iptables-services` is needed.

```
# yum install iptables-services
# systemctl enable iptables
# systemctl start iptables
```

Backup current rules:

```
# cp /etc/sysconfig/iptables /etc/sysconfig/iptables.bak
```

Persist rules to file:

```
# iptables-save >/etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Comment: Thanks! For a Debian-based distro, is it `apt install iptables-services`? Also, what does it do? Can you add some more details? This would be great for future reference. Like: is `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` read on each boot? Or is it specific, if and only if `iptables-services` is installed?

Comment: @Basj actually the logic is same just packages and related file names are different.

Comment: @Basj yes correct. Also for some additional features like creation of systemd service unit you better install `netfilter-persistent` fully described here https://askubuntu.com/a/1072948/722342